# Weird Disk space usage Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, disk-space, ubuntu-server, logrotate

I have an ubuntu 10.04 server. For the past couple weeks, or as long as I can remember my disk space was going down by about 1 kb per minute (I assume from the massive logs). However all of a sudden today my disk space shot up from 1 gb available to 10 gb available. What could have been the reason, was logrotate doing something?

Comment: Did you reboot? Restart a service?

Comment: yes, but I have it set to do this daily

Comment: Yes what? Yes you rebooted or yes you restarted a service? Which service? What do you have it set to do daily? Is your disk space still decreasing by 1kb/min? Some distros only clear the /tmp folder every few reboots. We need some more information on what exactly you have running on your machine. 1kb/min is not normal unless this is a server with VERY heavy use.